# How can I shuffle an array/hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, shuffle

For learning purposes, what is this called? Is the object being created an array or a hash?

```
stack_of_cards = []
```

This is how I'm filling it:

```
stack_of_cards << Card.new("A", "Spades", 1)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("2", "Spades", 2)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("3", "Spades", 3)
...
```

Here is my Card class:

```
class Card

  attr_accessor :number, :suit, :value

  def initialize(number, suit, value)
    @number = number
    @suit = suit
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@number} of #{@suit}"
  end
end
```

I'd like to shuffle the elements in this array/hash (what is this called? :S)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can imagine you skipped Struct, but when you have time, look into it.

Answer (score 21):

```
stack_of_cards.shuffle
```

It is an Array, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html for more information.

I've written the [functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) form, which returns a new Array, and it's the new one that's shuffled. You can instead use:

```
stack_of_cards.shuffle!
```

...to shuffle the array in-place.

Comment: Word? There is actually a shuffle method on the Array class? Jesus!

Comment: This doesn't modify the array though. FYI. :P *disregard, you edited your answer...*

Comment: Looking at the Changelog, #shuffle seems to have been added on the last day of August in 2006, which would result in it first appearing, I think, in 1.8.6. That's certainly too late for some editions of various Ruby books.

Comment: For more fun, there is Array.sample , which returns a random element from your array. Use Array.sample(3) if you want 3 random elements.

Comment: "That's certainly too late for some editions of various Ruby books". Most definitely. Ruby is one of the fastest moving targets for a publisher it seems. I don't even wanna talk about finding good Rails books because they're out of date when they're published. :-)

Answer (score 13):

If you want to shuffle a hash you can use something like this:

```
class Hash
  def shuffle
    Hash[self.to_a.sample(self.length)]
  end

  def shuffle!
    self.replace(self.shuffle)
  end
end
```

I've posted this answer since I always find this question if I search for "ruby shuffle hash".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [using the shuffle method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060660/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-hash-in-ruby/5060675#5060675), you can use the sort method:

```
array.sort {|a, b| rand <=> rand }
```

This may be of use if you are using an older version of Ruby where `shuffle` is not implemented. As with `shuffle!`, you can use `sort!` to work on the existing array.

Comment: That do not work well. `[1, 2, 3].sort { rand.round }` always returns `[1, 2, 3]` or `[3, 2, 1]`. The right way should be `[1, 2, 3].sort { rand <=> rand }`, or `[1, 2, 3].sort_by { rand }` (avoid if `shuffle` can be used).

Comment: mention for HASH also if you know... incase

Comment: This is a really ineffective way to shuffle. Sorting algorithms don't compare every element to every element. They implicitly encode inferences like "if I compared A as being less than B, and that B is less than C, then I can infer A is less than C without checking." the result is *heavily* skewed, as described here (in ObjC, but equally applicable) https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/06/sorting-nsmutablearray-with-random.html I would request that you delete or change this answer

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to get crazy and write your own in-place shuffle method, you could do something like this.

```
 def shuffle_me(array)
   (array.size-1).downto(1) do |i|
     j = rand(i+1)
     array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
   end

   array
 end
```

Comment: Why `rand(array.size-1)` and not `rand(array.size)`? `rand` is not inclusive, so for example `rand(5)` will output numbers from 0 - 4.

Comment: Yeah, there were actually a few issues with my previous implementation.  I revised my above method to reflect the Knuth Shuffle algorithm.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Fisher_and_Yates.27_original_method

Answer (score 1):

For arrays:

```
array.shuffle
[1, 3, 2].shuffle
#=> [3, 1, 2]
```

For hashes:

```
Hash[*hash.to_a.shuffle.flatten]
Hash[*{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.to_a.shuffle.flatten(1)]
#=> {:b=>2, :c=>3, :a=>1}
#=> {:c=>3, :a=>1, :b=>2}
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
# Also works for hashes containing arrays
Hash[*{a: [1, 2], b: [2, 3], c: [3, 4]}.to_a.shuffle.flatten(1)]
#=> {:b=>2, :c=>3, :a=>1}
#=> {:c=>[3, 4], :a=>[1, 2], :b=>[2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but maybe help for someone else. I used it to create a card game, that's what @davissp14 wrote, it's called "Fisher-Yates algorithm"

```
module FisherYates

  def self.shuffle(numbers)
    n = numbers.length
    while n > 0 
      x = rand(n-=1)
      numbers[x], numbers[n] = numbers[n], numbers[x]
    end
    return numbers
  end

end
```

Now you can use it as:

```
numbers_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
asnwer = FisherYates.shuffle(numbers_array)
return answer.inspect
```

https://dev.to/linuxander/fisher-yates-shuffle-with-ruby-1p7h

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shuffle a hash, but don't want to overload the Hash class, you can use the sort function and then convert it back to a hash with the to_h function (Ruby 2.1+):

```
a = {"a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3}
puts a.inspect
a = a.sort {|a, b| rand <=> rand }.to_h
puts a.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

For an array:

`array.shuffle`

For a hash:

`hash.sort_by{ rand() }`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative hash shuffle is ..

```
hash.to_a.shuffle.to_h
```